Python discord bot joins the voice channel, but no audio is played
I was making a bot for a discord server, and the bot will join the voice call and add the song to the queue. However it will not play any sounds. There are no errors in the console, and the soung is loaded to the queue, just no sound from the bot.
Here is the code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False


        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
            return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            #self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS),after=lambda e: self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.isconnected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e:self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p"], help="Play the selected song from yt")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Connected to a voice channel")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pause the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resume playing the current song")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases = ["s"], help="Skip the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="View the queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx, *args):
        retval = ''

        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 4:
                break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in the queue")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops current song and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="kick the bot from the VC")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()

I'm sorry if this is easy to see, but I'm relatively new to this
